# Pandas read_html() converts numbers in table to string

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have an html table that I want to convert to a pandas dataframe.  I'm using `pandas.read_html()` and it works alright except it reads in the numbers in my table as strings.

```
table = html_table_here
table = '<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  '+table+'    \n</table>'
df_table = pandas.read_html(table,header=None,index_col=0)
df = pandas.concat(df_table)
```

And doing `print df["TASK_ID"][0]` returns `"3"` instead of `3`.

Is there anyway to preserve the type of the values in an html table when converting to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: You'd have to explicitly convert those values to numerical dtypes `df_table = df_table.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)` as it's can't guess here if the html values are str or numerical

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to explicitly convert those strings to numerical dtypes as it can't tell what the dtypes are when they're str in html, so calling [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects) should work:

```
df_table = df_table.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

Comment: TypeError: read_html() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert_numeric'